# Using a log file to log information of a datagram packet

Tags: java, logging

### Heading

Hi, I'm using `simpleFormatter` to log data concerning a packet in a log file named `projet.formatter.log` with Netbeans IDE but the log file it displays is in `XMLFormat` and not in simple readable format. Here is the code snippet

### Heading

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(log_projet.class.getName());
public log_projet(DatagramPacket sock) throws IOException{


    Handler fileHandler = null;
    Formatter simpleFormatter = null;

    try{
        fileHandler = new FileHandler("./projet.formatter.log"); // prints the log at a target destination
        simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "The packet is adressed to {0}", sock.getSocketAddress());// returns the address and the port number of the host
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "There are {0}" + " bytes of data ", sock.getLength());
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Time entred router{0}", temps_entree_paquet_dans_routeur());
        // add time transfer
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Time left router{0}", time_left_router());
        // source port and destination port
        //ip address of sender and receiver

        fileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter); // formats the logrecords
        fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    } catch(IOException ex){
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,"Error occured in file handler.",ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the formatter before you attach the FileHandler to the logger and start writting log messages.

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(log_projet.class.getName());
    public log_projet(DatagramPacket sock) throws IOException{


    Handler fileHandler = null;
    Formatter simpleFormatter = null;

    try{
        fileHandler = new FileHandler("./projet.formatter.log");
        simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter); // formats the logrecords
        fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "The packet is adressed to {0}", sock.getSocketAddress());// returns the address and the port number of the host
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "There are {0}" + " bytes of data ", sock.getLength());
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Time entred router{0}", temps_entree_paquet_dans_routeur());
        // add time transfer
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Time left router{0}", time_left_router());
        // source port and destination port
        //ip address of sender and receiver
    } catch(IOException ex){
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,"Error occured in file handler.",ex);
    }
}
```